# Using email HTML bulletproof background image, but getting a weird empty box

Tags: html, email, outlook, background-image

This is my code

```
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;border-collapse: collapse;background-image:image path;background-color:green;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position: center;" bgcolor="green" background="image path" valign="top">
                                       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000">
                <v:fill type="frame" src="image path" color="#7C64C3" />
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                <div><div style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;margin: 0;border: 0"><![endif]-->
```

Then my content, and then closing with

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]></div></div>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
```

I'm getting this on the corner-

[image: getting this weird box]

Comment: In which email client are you getting this rendering?

Comment: Outlook 2013, 2016, 2019 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had a background image in multiple spots and I didn't copy the end ifs on the last one.